# Table schema as DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I did a search and found some seemingly related answers, but they don't really do what I'm after.

Given a valid connection string and a table name, I want to get a `DataTable` of the table. I.e. if the table has a column called "Name", I want the DataTable set up so I can do `dt["Name"] = "blah"`;

The trick is, I don't want to hard code any of that stuff, I want to do it dynamically.

People tell you to use `SqlConnection.GetSchema`, but that gives you back a table with a bunch of stuff in it.

Everybody has random tricks like `TOP 0 * from the table` and get the schema from there, etc.

But is there a way to get the table with the primary keys, unique indexes, etc. Ie.. in the final format to do a bulk insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fillschema(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var connection = @"Your connection string";
var command = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Mapped);
```

This way you will have an empty `DataTable` with columns and keys defined and ready to use in code like `dataTable["Name"] = "blah";`.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I'm looking for :) I was afraid I was going to have to parse the column data from GetSchema().